# How to update the transform position of custom shape polygon after moving it

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

After drawing the polygon, if I move any points on polygon to re-shape it. The shape of polygon is updated correctly, but If I move the polygon to anywhere on the canvas before update the polygon shape, my polygon jump back to position where it was created. Please give me some advice on what I'm missing or did wrong. Thank you.

Step to reproduce

1. click on Draw Polygon
2. draw a polygon
3. move the polygon
4. reshape the polygon by move the point on polygon

Here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ckitisak/3rwv1ae9

```js
/**
 * based on:
 * 1. https://codepen.io/durga598/pen/gXQjdw?editors=0010
 * 2. http://fabricjs.com/custom-controls-polygon
 */


let activeLine;
let activeShape;
let canvas;
let lineArray = [];
let pointArray = [];
let drawMode = false;

function initCanvas() {
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
    canvas.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)';
    canvas.setHeight(500);
    canvas.setWidth(500);

    fabric.Object.prototype.originX = 'center';
    fabric.Object.prototype.originY = 'center';

    canvas.on('mouse:down', onMouseDown);
    canvas.on('mouse:move', onMouseMove);
    canvas.on('object:moving', onObjectMove);
}

function onMouseDown(options) {
    if (drawMode) {
        if (options.target && options.target.id === pointArray[0].id) {
            // when click on the first point
            generatePolygon(pointArray);
        } else {
            addPoint(options);
        }
    }
}

function onMouseMove(options) {
    if (drawMode) {
        if (activeLine && activeLine.class === 'line') {
            const pointer = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
            activeLine.set({
                x2: pointer.x,
                y2: pointer.y
            });
            const points = activeShape.get('points');
            points[pointArray.length] = {
                x: pointer.x,
                y: pointer.y,
            };
            activeShape.set({
                points
            });
        }
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}

function onObjectMove(option) {
    const object = option.target;
    object._calcDimensions();
    object.setCoords();    
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function toggleDrawPolygon(event) {
    if (drawMode) {
        // stop draw mode
        activeLine = null;
        activeShape = null;
        lineArray = [];
        pointArray = [];
        canvas.selection = true;
        drawMode = false;
    } else {
        // start draw mode
        canvas.selection = false;
        drawMode = true;
    }
}

function addPoint(options) {
    const pointOption = {
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        radius: 5,
        fill: '#ffffff',
        stroke: '#333333',
        strokeWidth: 0.5,
        left: options.e.layerX / canvas.getZoom(),
        top: options.e.layerY / canvas.getZoom(),
        selectable: false,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        objectCaching: false,
    };
    const point = new fabric.Circle(pointOption);

    if (pointArray.length === 0) {
        // fill first point with red color
        point.set({
            fill: 'red'
        });
    }

    const linePoints = [
        options.e.layerX / canvas.getZoom(),
        options.e.layerY / canvas.getZoom(),
        options.e.layerX / canvas.getZoom(),
        options.e.layerY / canvas.getZoom(),
    ];
    const lineOption = {
        strokeWidth: 2,
        fill: '#999999',
        stroke: '#999999',
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'center',
        selectable: false,
        hasBorders: false,
        hasControls: false,
        evented: false,
        objectCaching: false,
    };
    const line = new fabric.Line(linePoints, lineOption);
    line.class = 'line';

    if (activeShape) {
        const pos = canvas.getPointer(options.e);
        const points = activeShape.get('points');
        points.push({
            x: pos.x,
            y: pos.y
        });
        const polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
            stroke: '#333333',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            fill: '#cccccc',
            opacity: 0.3,
            selectable: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false,
            evented: false,
            objectCaching: false,
        });
        canvas.remove(activeShape);
        canvas.add(polygon);
        activeShape = polygon;
        canvas.renderAll();
    } else {
        const polyPoint = [{
            x: options.e.layerX / canvas.getZoom(),
            y: options.e.layerY / canvas.getZoom(),
        }, ];
        const polygon = new fabric.Polygon(polyPoint, {
            stroke: '#333333',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            fill: '#cccccc',
            opacity: 0.3,
            selectable: false,
            hasBorders: false,
            hasControls: false,
            evented: false,
            objectCaching: false,
        });
        activeShape = polygon;
        canvas.add(polygon);
    }

    activeLine = line;
    pointArray.push(point);
    lineArray.push(line);

    canvas.add(line);
    canvas.add(point);
}

function generatePolygon(pointArray) {
    const points = [];
    // collect points and remove them from canvas
    for (const point of pointArray) {
        points.push({
            x: point.left,
            y: point.top,
        });
        canvas.remove(point);
    }

    // remove lines from canvas
    for (const line of lineArray) {
        canvas.remove(line);
    }

    // remove selected Shape and Line 
    canvas.remove(activeShape).remove(activeLine);

    // create polygon from collected points
    const polygon = new fabric.Polygon(points, {
        id: new Date().getTime(),
        stroke: '#eee',
        fill: '#f00',
        objectCaching: false,
        moveable: false,
    });
    canvas.add(polygon);

    toggleDrawPolygon();
    editPolygon();
}

/**
 * define a function that can locate the controls.
 * this function will be used both for drawing and for interaction.
 */
function polygonPositionHandler(dim, finalMatrix, fabricObject) {
    const transformPoint = {
        x: fabricObject.points[this.pointIndex].x - fabricObject.pathOffset.x,
        y: fabricObject.points[this.pointIndex].y - fabricObject.pathOffset.y,
    };
    return fabric.util.transformPoint(transformPoint, fabricObject.calcTransformMatrix());
}

/**
 * define a function that will define what the control does
 * this function will be called on every mouse move after a control has been
 * clicked and is being dragged.
 * The function receive as argument the mouse event, the current trasnform object
 * and the current position in canvas coordinate
 * transform.target is a reference to the current object being transformed,
 */
function actionHandler(eventData, transform, x, y) {
    const polygon = transform.target;
    const currentControl = polygon.controls[polygon.__corner];
    const mouseLocalPosition = polygon.toLocalPoint(new fabric.Point(x, y), 'center', 'center');
    const size = polygon._getTransformedDimensions(0, 0);
    const finalPointPosition = {
        x: (mouseLocalPosition.x * polygon.width) / size.x + polygon.pathOffset.x,
        y: (mouseLocalPosition.y * polygon.height) / size.y + polygon.pathOffset.y,
    };
    polygon.points[currentControl.pointIndex] = finalPointPosition;
    return true;
}

/**
 * define a function that can keep the polygon in the same position when we change its
 * width/height/top/left.
 */
function anchorWrapper(anchorIndex, fn) {
    return function(eventData, transform, x, y) {
        const fabricObject = transform.target;
        const point = {
            x: fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].x - fabricObject.pathOffset.x,
            y: fabricObject.points[anchorIndex].y - fabricObject.pathOffset.y,
        };

        // update the transform border
        fabricObject._setPositionDimensions({});

        // Now newX and newY represent the point position with a range from
        // -0.5 to 0.5 for X and Y.
        const newX = point.x / fabricObject.width;
        const newY = point.y / fabricObject.height;

        // Fabric supports numeric origins for objects with a range from 0 to 1.
        // This let us use the relative position as an origin to translate the old absolutePoint.
        const absolutePoint = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, fabricObject.calcTransformMatrix());
        fabricObject.setPositionByOrigin(absolutePoint, newX + 0.5, newY + 0.5);

        // action performed
        return fn(eventData, transform, x, y);
    };
}

function editPolygon() {
    let activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!activeObject) {
        activeObject = canvas.getObjects()[0];
        canvas.setActiveObject(activeObject);
    }

    activeObject.edit = true;
    activeObject.objectCaching = false;

    const lastControl = activeObject.points.length - 1;
    activeObject.cornerStyle = 'circle';
    activeObject.controls = activeObject.points.reduce((acc, point, index) => {
        acc['p' + index] = new fabric.Control({
            positionHandler: polygonPositionHandler,
            actionHandler: anchorWrapper(index > 0 ? index - 1 : lastControl, actionHandler),
            actionName: 'modifyPolygon',
            pointIndex: index,
        });
        return acc;
    }, {});

    activeObject.hasBorders = false;

    canvas.requestRenderAll();
}

function resizePolygon() {
    let activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject();
    if (!activeObject) {
        activeObject = canvas.getObjects()[0];
        canvas.setActiveObject(activeObject);
    }

    activeObject.edit = false;
    activeObject.objectCaching = false;
    activeObject.controls = fabric.Object.prototype.controls;
    activeObject.cornerStyle = 'rect';
    activeObject.cornerColor = '#f00';
    activeObject.cornerStrokeColor = '#000';
    activeObject.transparentCorners = false;
    activeObject.borderColor = '#000';
    activeObject.hasBorders = true;

    canvas.requestRenderAll();
}

initCanvas();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fabric@4.0.0-beta.12/dist/fabric.js"></script>

<button type="button" onclick="toggleDrawPolygon()">Draw Polygon</button>
<button type="button" onclick="editPolygon()">Edit Polygon</button>
<button type="button" onclick="resizePolygon()">Resize/Move Polygon</button>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: http://fabricjs.com/custom-controls-polygon Look for how the exact same functionality is obtained here. Version 4 used in your fiddle has been created exactly to solve those problems.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi Thank you very much. the problem is solved now.